# Which is correct, to be built or to build?

Tags: infinitives

> 1. Robots are too complex **to be built**.
> 2. Robots are too complex **to build**.

I'd like to know which is correct.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Both sentences are correct and have essentially the same meaning.

However the first sentence

> Robots are too complex **to be built**.

Has greater emphasis on being **not buildable**

> Robots are too complex **to be built** *(ever, by anyone)*.

> Robots are too complex **to build**.

Could also mean the same as **to be built**, but can also mean

> by ***someone*** at this present time ***given the current circumstances***
>
> **Robots are too complex** *(for me)* **to build**
>   **Robots are too complex to build** *(on our budget)*

Answer (score 1):

They mean much the same.

Perhaps some light on any nuanced differences can be shed by adding an agent phrase and then examining the prepositions we use with each.

> A microbe is too small *for* the naked eye {to see}.
>
> A microbe is too small {to be seen} *by* the naked eye.
>
> The car is too expensive *for* the average wage-earner {to buy}.
>
> The car is too expensive {to be bought} *by* the average wage-earner.

Semantically, we supply [the implied object] with the first (if it is not present, though it can be):

A microbe is too small *for* the naked eye {to see} [it].
The car is too expensive *for* the average wage-earner {to buy} [it].

but that step is not necessary with the second, the **by** form.

The idea is

the naked eye cannot see the microbe

the average wage-earner cannot afford the car

Is this idea expressed with any greater directness or emphasis by either of the versions?

the naked-eye cannot see it
   it cannot be seen by the naked eye

the average wage-earner cannot afford it
   it cannot be afforded by the average wage-earner

Answer (score 0):

1. The active infinitive is prefered if you're thinking more about the person who will do the action.
2. The passive infinitive is used  if you are thinking more about the action, or the person/thing that the action is done to.

   - *The **papers to be arranged** are in the desk.* (NOT <s>*The papers to arrange are in the desk.*</s>)

The thing is, passive infinitive is normally used after *be* forms (*am, is, are*):

> » *Robots **are** too complex **to be built**.*